# Modelling a domain class as an RDD

Tags: apache-spark

We are considering redeveloping our existing application using Spark.
Our existing domain model (currently `C#` classes)  would be remodeled as an RDD, and the logic which currently modifies the domain model would be refactored into functions which transform the RDD.

The question is how to best model a domain class as an RDD.
The simplest approach would be to model it as a `Map<String, Any>`.
This could then be loaded as an RDD into Spark using `sparkContext.parallelize(map).`

The alternative would be to create a domain class in Scala (perhaps as a `case class`) and load this as an RDD. Every element (or 'row') in the RDD would then be one instance of the class. However, is this considered a correct approach or best practice? And, if it is an approach which makes sense, how can a Scala class be loaded into Spark as an RDD?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This works:

create `case class`

```
case class User(username:String, age:Int, gender:String)
```

create instances

```
var user1 = User("john", 46, "f")
var user2 = User("paul", 44, "m")
var user3 = User("miriam", 22, "m")
```

create list of user instances, and from that create an RDD

```
val users = List(user1, user2, user3)
val usersRDD = sc.parallelize(users)
```

create function to modify each `User` instance

```
def incrementAge(u:User) = {
     val user = u.copy(age = t.age+1)
     user
}
```

and pass it to the RDD

```
val modifiedRDD = usersRDD.map {x => incrementAge(x) }
```

confirm

```
usersRDD.foreach { println }
```

Does anyone with experience of Spark have an approach which is more recommended?